# Annotate faceted plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet

I am working on the dataset reported here below (pre.sss)

```
pre.sss <- pre.sss <- structure(list(Pretest.num = c(63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 4,2, 1), stress = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,1L), .Label = c("[0,6]", "(6,9]"), class = "factor"), time = c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L), after = structure(c(2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"),id = c("call_fam", "call_fam", "call_fam", "call_fam", "call_fam","call_fam", "call_fam", "counselor", "counselor", "counselor")), .Names = c("Pretest.num", "stress", "time", "after","id"), reshapeLong = structure(list(varying = structure(list(after = c("after.call.fam", "after.speak", "after.send.email","after.send.card", "after.attend", "after.fam.mtg", "after.sup.grp","after.counselor")), .Names = "after", v.names = "after", times = 1:8),v.names = "after", idvar = "Pretest.num", timevar = "time"), .Names = c("varying","v.names", "idvar", "timevar")), row.names = c("63.1", "62.1","61.1", "60.1", "59.1", "58.1", "57.1", "4.8", "2.8", "1.8"), class = "data.frame")
```

and I need to plot the counts of several categorical variables according to a specific level of another categorical variable ('stress'): so, a faceted bobble-lot would do the job in my case
So what I do is the following:

```
ylabels = c('call_fam' = "call fam.member for condolences",
            'speak' = "speak to fam.member in person", 
            'send.email' = "send condolence email to fam.member",
            'send.card' = "send condolence card/letter to fam.member", 
            'attend' = "attend funeral/wake", 
            'fam.mtg' = "provide fam.meeting",
            'sup.grp' = "suggest attending support grp.",
            'counselor' = "make referral to bereavement counselor" )

p = ggplot(pre.sss, aes(x = after, y = id)) + 
    geom_count(alpha = 0.5, col = 'darkblue') + 
    scale_size(range = c(1,30)) +
    theme(legend.position = 'none') +
    xlab("Response") + 
    ylab("What did you do after learning about death?") + 
    scale_y_discrete(labels = ylabels) +
    facet_grid(.~ pre.sss$stress, labeller = as_labeller(stress.labels))
```

and I obtain the following image, exactly as I want.

[image]

Now I would like to label each bubble with the count with which the corresponding data appear in the dataset.

```
dat = data.frame(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]][, c('x', 'y', 'PANEL', 'n')])
dat$PANEL = ifelse(dat$PANEL==1, "[0,6]", "(6-9]")
colnames(dat) = c('x', 'y', 'stress', 'n')

p + geom_text(aes(x, y, label = n, group = NULL), data = dat)
```

This gives me the following error I really can't understand.

```
> p +  geom_text(aes(x, y, label=n, group=NULL), data=dat)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PANEL", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 504 rows, data has 46
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks!

EM

Comment: Without a sample of your data, I can't reproduce it.  But at a guess, you're defining data, x and y in your initial `ggplot()` **and** in your `geom_text()` call.  You could try `ggplot() + geom_count(data = pre.sss, aes(x = after, y = id) + geom_text(data = pre.sss, aes(x = after,y = id, label = n, group = NULL)`

Comment: Please do not use dropbox to share your data. Not everyone's going to download something from an external link into their own computers. Including the results of `dput(pre.sss)` in your would be preferable.

Comment: _"This gives me an error I really can't understand."_ We can't either, because you didn't post it. And I can't recreate without some data.

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for the bad posting. I have attached a hopefully more reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

The function you refer to as your labeller function is missing from this example still. `geom_count` uses `stat_sum`, which calculates a parameter `n`, the number of observations at that point. Because you can use this calculated parameter, you don't actually have to assign the plot to a variable and pull out its data, as you did with `ggplot_build`.

This should do what you're looking for:

```
ggplot(pre.sss, aes(x = after, y = id)) + 
    geom_count(alpha = 0.5, col = 'darkblue') + 
# note the following line
    stat_sum(mapping = aes(label = ..n..), geom = "text") +
    scale_size(range = c(1,30)) +
    theme(legend.position = 'none') +
    xlab("Response") + 
    ylab("What did you do after learning about death?") + 
    scale_y_discrete(labels = ylabels) +
    facet_grid(.~ stress)
```

The line I added computes the same thing as what's behind the scenes in `geom_count`, but gives it a text geom instead, with the label mapped to that computed parameter `n`.